# Powershell v2, Compress file with wildcard?

Tags: powershell, compression

Is there a way to compress a file using PowerShell 2.0 when I don't know the exact name of the file? I know the first few letters, so I could use a wildcard character.

Lastly, the script would have to be able to be called from a batch file.

Comment: P.S. Unfortunately, I do not have the ability to install anything additional to my workstation.

Answer (score 0):

There are no cmdlets to compress files in PowerShell 2. You can use the `Shell.Application` COM-object, but I would recommend a module like the [PSCX (PowerShell Community Extensions) 2.1.1](http://pscx.codeplex.com/releases/view/98267) which has a `Write-Zip` function, then you should be able to do something like this (untested):

```
#Get files/directories starting with "abc"
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\rootfolder -Filter "abc*" -Recurse |
#Get only files
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
#Compress to zip
Write-Zip -OutputPath "MyZip.zip"
```

Or in case there are multiple hits and you want them separate

```
#Get files/directories starting with "abc"
Get-ChildItem -Path c:\rootfolder -Filter "abc*" -Recurse |
#Get only files
Where-Object { !$_.PSIsContainer } |
ForEach-Object { Write-Zip -Path $_.FullName -OutputPath "$($_.Name).zip" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately, I am not able to add extensions to my workstation; it's locked down pretty well. I'll ask, but I'm pretty sure the answer will be "no".

Comment: Then you have to use a COMObject like I mentioned. You can try the script here: http://superuser.com/questions/460317/powershell-cmd-script-of-out-zip-ps1

Comment: I tried the script & batch file from that link, but like the original poster in that thread, the result is an empty ZIP file. I'm missing something. Can you get that example to work?

Comment: The shell objects are not designed for interactive use, not automation. It is unlikely that this will work reliably.

Comment: Ok. Then download 7z or something that supports command line and use that. Or download a .net library for zip support. :-)